# Swift and Firebase: Generating JWT token and authenticating user on getStream.io

Tags: swift, firebase, getstream-io

I am reaching out to seek your assistance with an issue I am facing regarding the generation of JWT tokens for authenticated users using Firebase.

I have implemented Firebase Authentication in my application to authenticate users using various methods such as email/password, Google Sign-In, and Facebook Login. Once a user is successfully authenticated, I would like to generate a JWT token to further enhance the security and enable additional functionality in my application.

However, I am unsure about the exact steps and procedures to follow in order to generate the JWT tokens for authenticated users

How can I retrieve the authenticated user's ID token from Firebase Authentication? I understand that the ID token represents the user's identity and is a crucial component in generating the JWT token.

What are the recommended best practices for securely generating JWT tokens? Are there any specific encryption or signing algorithms that I should consider? How can I ensure the integrity and confidentiality of the tokens?

final class ChatManager {
static let shared = ChatManager()

```
private var chatClient: ChatClient?
var streamChat: StreamChat? {
    return chatClient.flatMap { StreamChat(chatClient: $0) }
}

private init() {}

func setup(userId: String, name: String?, username: String?, imageUrl: String?) async throws {
    let apiKey = APIKey("STREAM_API_KEY")
    let tokenProvider = { (userId: String) -> TokenProvider in
        guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            throw ChatManagerError.currentUserNotFound
        }
        let firebaseToken = try await currentUser.getIDTokenResult(completion: nil).token ?? ""
        return .development(userId: userId, token: firebaseToken)
    }
    
    let config = ChatClientConfig(apiKey: apiKey)
    chatClient = ChatClient(config: config)
    
    try connectUser(userId: userId, name: name, username: username, imageUrl: imageUrl)
}

private func connectUser(userId: String, name: String?, username: String?, imageUrl: String?) throws {
    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        throw ChatManagerError.currentUserNotFound
    }
    
    try chatClient?.connectUser(
        userInfo: .init(id: userId,
                        name: name ?? currentUser.displayName ?? "Unknown",
                        imageURL: URL(string: imageUrl ?? "")),
        token: Token(stringLiteral: userId)
    )
}
```

}

inal class ChatManager {
static let shared = ChatManager()

```
private var chatClient: ChatClient?
var streamChat: StreamChat? {
    return chatClient.flatMap { StreamChat(chatClient: $0) }
}

private init() {}

func setup(userId: String, name: String?, username: String?, imageUrl: String?) async throws {
    let apiKey = APIKey("STREAM_API_KEY")
    let tokenProvider = { (userId: String) -> TokenProvider in
        guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            throw ChatManagerError.currentUserNotFound
        }
        let firebaseToken = try await currentUser.getIDTokenResult(completion: nil).token ?? ""
        return .development(userId: userId, token: firebaseToken)
    }
    
    let config = ChatClientConfig(apiKey: apiKey)
    chatClient = ChatClient(config: config)
    
    try connectUser(userId: userId, name: name, username: username, imageUrl: imageUrl)
}

private func connectUser(userId: String, name: String?, username: String?, imageUrl: String?) throws {
    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        throw ChatManagerError.currentUserNotFound
    }
    
    chatClient?.connectUser(
        userInfo: .init(id: userId,
                        name: name ?? currentUser.displayName ?? "Unknown",
                        imageURL: URL(string: imageUrl ?? "")),
        token: Token(stringLiteral: userId)
    )
}
```

}

Comment: Hey,
from the Stream side, we have a documentation page on [how to generate tokens](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/react/tokens_and_authentication/) using only your API key, secret, and the `userId`. However, this is code that should be run on the server.

One solution would be to take the user id from your authentication system (Firebase Auth) and register them on the Stream backend with the same `userId`.

Let me know if you have more questions on the process, happy to help! :)